# How to make a gradle task execute twice instead of showing up-to-date status?

Tags: gradle

I have added a task "killTomcat" in my build.gradle file to kill the running tomcat process.
It executes a couple of tasks and then it starts tomcat for test execution, and stops it afterwards. Sometimes, it is not able to stop tomcat. So, I want killTomcat to be executed when tomcat is running. But Instead of executing the task, It outputs "UP-TO-DATE" status.

How to make the task execute twice?

```
   task tomcatKill {
       println(':tomcatKill');
       try{
          def process_id = ['/bin/bash', '-c', /ps aux | grep 'tomcat' |  grep  -v  'grep'|  awk  '{print $2}'/].execute();
          process_id.waitFor();
          def pid =  process_id.text
          String killCmd = 'kill -9 ';
          killCmd = killCmd.concat(pid.toString());
          killCmd.execute();
     }catch(Exception ex) {
          println("No tomcat running..");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Could you show the code of your task? Up-to-date-checks are usually performed for tasks with input/output files (Copy, Delete ...).

Comment: @abhijit it does not solve my problem because there i wanted to know how to do the ordering of tasks. and here i want to know why the task is not running the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `gradle killTomcat --rerun-tasks`

See more in [CLI Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html)

Comment: Hi @Eric I don't want to run the task from command line. I want this task to be executed once again during the build process.

Comment: Well I think it might be better to have a separate task that performs the actions of the original twice. `2.times { /* code that does what you want */ }`. I can't think of a way to invoke the same task twice in one build unless you copy it.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with this approach, but if you must, you can disable up-to-date check. In the task definition, put `outputs.upToDateWhen { false }`. Your question is vague, so I'm not clear how you want to run the task twice. If you've not figured that out, post your `build.gradle` and clearly specify when in the build lifecycle you want this task to run.

That said, the JVM was created to decouple the code from the host system. This task, and your approach of killing a Tomcat process on the host system is against what Java was created for, not to mention this won't work on Windows. If you need a web container for testing, see [embedded tomcat](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html) or [arquillian](http://arquillian.org/guides/shrinkwrap_introduction/)